# Bash Read CSV value from Variable in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

So in a script I have a variable that changes each time the script is run.  The variable is IP_PING.  It is basically a list of if address seperated by commas.

I want the script to take each ip addess in the csv variable and ping it.  The example below works fine if I only have one ip address in the variable.

```
IP_PING="192.168.1.1"
echo "$IP_PING" | while read -r -d, ip1 
 do
   ping -c 4 "$ip1" >/dev/null 
     if [ $?  -ne 0 ]; then
     echo "Ping fail"
     else
     echo "Ping success"
     fi
 done
```

But if I change the IP_Ping variable to = "192.168.1.1,192.168.100.1"  The script only reads the first value 192.168.1.1.  Is "while read" the wrong command to use for this. It is reading each value as a seperate column. I want all the values in a single column and then do the while on each value.  If that makes sense.

Comment: Sounds like you want `IFS=, read -r -a ips <<<"$IP_PING"`, and then `for ip in "${ips[@]}"; do ping -c 4 "$ip"; done`, or such.

Comment: To explain in general, though: `-d` specifies the delimiter **between separate records**, whereas `IFS` specifies the delimiter between fields within a record.

Comment: ...btw, in general, it's better practice to write `if ping -c 4; then` rather than using `$?`. The latter is fragile -- easy to add a new line of logging or such and modify your last-command-exit-status value by mistake.

Comment: (As another aside -- all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the system or shell, whereas names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application use; see relevant spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph).

Comment: *for a in $(echo $IP_PING | tr ‘,’ ‘ ‘); do ... ; done*

Comment: Charles this works great.  Thanks for the tips.

Comment: So based on what you said this works: IP_PING="192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3"
IFS=, read -r -a ips <<<"$IP_PING"
    for ip in "${ips[@]}"
    do
    if ping -c 4 "$ip" >/dev/null; then 
    echo "successful ping of $ip" 
    else echo "failed ping of $ip"  
    fi
    done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"192.168.1.1,192.168.100.1"`

Here is your issue. The problem is that when the while loop is reading, after the first iteration there is no more commas so it hits the end and quits. `"192.168.1.1,192.168.100.1,"` should show the way you are intending.

As other's have suggested in the comments, I would go with a for loop myself, but to with closet to how you were trying to implement it, this would work for you:

```
IP_PING="192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3"
while read -r ip1 ; do
   ping -c 4 "$ip1" >/dev/null 
     if [ $?  -ne 0 ]; then
     echo "Ping fail"
     else
     echo "Ping success"
     fi
done < <(echo $IP_PING |tr ',' '\n')
```

`< <(echo $IP_PING |tr ',' '\n')` is process substitution. To put it simply it will "pipe" the output into the while loop. The difference from a normal pipe being that it creates one less process; the actual pipe creates a process itself.

Using [process substitution](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwil0c_W04DXAhXn44MKHZ7ED1EQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftldp.org%2FLDP%2Fabs%2Fhtml%2Fprocess-sub.html&usg=AOvVaw0UtGq9fiGA2FwEpveS6I9M) will also keep the while loop in the current environment as well. (vs a while loop usually takes a 'snapshot' of the env and uses that during the loop, then it disappears when the loop ends) Meaning, with process substitution, that processes in the while loop will be able to see changes in env variables of the parent while it is looping, AND variables assigned within the loop will also still be available in the parent after it ends.

Comment: I get it.  So you are basically translating the csv into a single column of values and reading the values one row/line at a time.  Where as in Charles example above he is reading the csv values into a single column array and reading them that way.  At least that is my understanding.  I agree with you, the array way seems cleaner, but your example works as well.  Thanks.